# Вывод массива как элемента ArrayList

Tags: java, кодировка

Всем привет.

Решил поработать с массивами, но сразу же возникли проблемы...

Имеется такая конструкция:

```
ArrayList<double[]> listTest = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

в listTest я добавляю массив:

```
double[] mass = new double[10];
listTest.add(mass);
```

Все, вроде бы, проходит отлично, но встает вопрос: Как вытащить массив от туда?

Если писать так:

```
listTest.get(0);
```

То выводятся кракозябры..Как же его вывести?) Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы выводите `double[]` из `ArrayList`, хотя хотите получить просто `double`

```
listTest.get(0)[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо! It Works!)